# Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: flutter, gradle

#### Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'. > Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.       > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.          > Manifest file does not exist: C:\Users\User\Desktop\FYP-1\Project 1\itech\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

-need help for FYP using flutter

```
The file exist in the folder.
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.itech">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="itech">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"

            android:value="2"/>
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

-This is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    // this is where we are going to find the libraries defined in "dependencies block" at below
   ext{
       kotlin_version="1.5.20"
   }

    repositories {
        google()

        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }

    // everything listed in the dependencies is actually a plugin, which we'll do "apply plugin" in our module level gradle file.
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1' // this is android gradle plugin
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // kotlin gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' //4.3.10
        //compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0'   //Android Application Plugin
    //id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() // Consider removing as it's being phased out
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

/*tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}*/

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    // Add other Android configurations as needed


}
```

- This is app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34 // Replace 34 with a target API level for your app
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin' // Merge Kotlin source directory
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.itech"

        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 34 //flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

        //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10" // Replace 1.7.10 with your desired version
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation project(':app')

    //implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Add this line if you use any Firebase services
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```